# Oracle Forms compiler mark a type as function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I'm making a procedure inside an Oracle Form that calls a backtracking which inserts in a table (the solution table). That backtracking is fed by a varray (ítem_array) of ítems (beans). Problem is the compiler says that there is no function name ítem.

existing objects in the database:

```
CREATE TYPE item IS object( NUM_OPERACIO NUMBER, TITULS NUMBER); 
CREATE TYPE item_array IS VARRAY(1000) OF item;
create table my_table (NUM_OPERACIO NUMBER, TITULS NUMBER);
insert into my_table ( NUM_OPERACIO,TITULS ) values (1,10);
insert into my_table ( NUM_OPERACIO,TITULS ) values (2,20)
insert into my_table ( NUM_OPERACIO,TITULS ) values (3,30)
```

procedure

```
PROCEDURE solver 
 IS
  arr item_array;  
 BEGIN

  SELECT item( NUM_OPERACIO,TITULS )
  BULK COLLECT INTO arr
  FROM   my_table;  

  delete from solucion ;

  backtra(arr,1,0,30);
END;
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: That looks fine, as long as everything is being done in the same schema (or privileges etc. are set up right), and the types were created successfully. What is the full error message stack you get?

Comment: error591. this function is no supported by client installed programs .
error 222. on this scope there is no function name ítem . 
error 0 . Statement ignore.

Comment: Under what schema did you create the objects `item`, `item_array` and `my_table`? make sure those objects have synonyms to APPS or they won't be visible to the default schema of Oracle Forms (`APPS`).

Answer (score 0):

That is a PLS error number. From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/plsus.htm#PLS-00049):

> "PLS-00591: this feature is not supported in client-side programs
>   Cause: One of the following features was used in a wrong context: pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION, dynamic SQL statements, (e.g. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE), and bulk binds. These listed features can only be used in server-side programs but not client-side programs."

Your code uses a bulk-bind, so the error fits. Forms PL/SQL and database PL/SQL are similar but they use different engines, and features supported in both is only a sub-set of all features in either.  The solution is to pass the array population into a database procedure and call it from Forms as needed.

Without knowing precisely what problem you're trying to solve, it's harder to give a better answer.